# Plotting Julia DataFrame columns that have whitespace in their names with Matplotlib

Tags: dataframe, matplotlib, julia, compatibility, removing-whitespace

I have `DataFrames` that have whitespace in their column names, because the CSV files they were generated from had whitespace in the names as well. The `DataFrame`s were generated with the lines

```
csvnames::Array{String,1} = filter(x -> endswith(x, ".csv"), readdir(CSV_DIR))
dfs::Dict{String, DataFrame} = Dict( csvnames[i] => CSV.File(CSV_DIR * csvnames[i]) |> DataFrame for i in 1:length(csvnames))
```

The `DataFrame`s have column names such as "Tehtävä 1", but none of the following expressions work when I try to access the column (here `ecols`  is a dataframe):

1. `plot = axes.plot(ecols[Symbol("Tehtävä 1")])` produces the error `TypeError("float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'PyCall.jlwrap'")`
2. `plot = axes.plot(ecols[:Tehtävä_1])` produces the error `ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: column name :Tehtävä_1 not found in the data frame; existing most similar names are: :Tehtävä 1`
3. `plot = axes.plot(ecols[:Tehtävä 1])` raises the error `ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching typed_hcat(::DataFrame, ::Symbol, ::Int64)`

It therefore seems that I have no way of plotting `DataFrame` columns that have spaces in their names. Printing them works just fine, as the line

```
println(ecols[Symbol("Tehtävä 1")])
```

produces and array of floats: `[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]`, which it is supposed to. Is Matplotlib just incompatible with `DataFrame`s with whitespace in their column names and if it is, how could I remove all whitespace from the columns of a Julia `DataFrame`?

## EDIT

I forgot to mention one very crucial point: the `DataFrame` contains `missing` values, which Matplotlib can't comprehend. This was causing error 1. I would still very much like to know if there is a way of getting rid of any whitespace in the table column names, possibly during the construction of the `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach works just fine, but it seems you are not using PyPlot.jl correctly (in particular you try to create a variable called `plot` which will overshadow `plot` function from PyPlot.jl).

To see that it works run:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(Symbol("Tehtävä 1") => 1.0:5.0)
5×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ Tehtävä 1 │
│     │ Float64   │
├─────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 1.0       │
│ 2   │ 2.0       │
│ 3   │ 3.0       │
│ 4   │ 4.0       │
│ 5   │ 5.0       │

julia> plot(df[Symbol("Tehtävä 1")])
1-element Array{PyCall.PyObject,1}:
 PyObject <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x000000003F9EE0B8>
```

and a plot is shown as expected.

**EDIT**

If you want to remove whitespace from column names of data frame `df` write:

```
names!(df, Symbol.(replace.(string.(names(df)), Ref(r"\s"=>""))))
```

Comment: You're right, of course, but I made an edit to my original post. I had completely forgotten, that Matplotlib cannot understand `missing` values, which was causing error #1. Changing those to `Nan` eliminated the issue.